# Nearest neighbor analysis that provides me a distribution of adjacent values?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, indexing, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to perform a nearest neighbor type of analysis on an array based on a given set of (x,y) coordinate indexes (NN.HEME_indices). The array on which I am evaluating is a 142x128 double that has a number of positive values throughout (ATV_ng_g_raw). In this work, I’m trying to limit this nearest neighbor analysis to within 10 pixels of the indexes (including 0 and 10).

My goal is to retrieve two histograms from this analysis. One graph is where the x-axis is the number of pixels away from the indexes (from 0 to 10, inclusive) and the y-axis is the average of the non-zero numbers at each distance. The second histogram is the same but the y-axis is the average of all numbers (including the 0’s) at each distance.

I’ve placed a .mat file (“NN_04062021.mat) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z4gcb0ujmzb8s0/NN_04062021.mat?dl=0).  This includes:

1. “NN” data structure – contains the coordinate indeces that serve as the central points, (HEME_indices; 2046 x 2 double). This was derived from a separate 142x128 double
2. ATV_ng_g_raw – contains the array on which I would be performing the nearest neighbor analysis (142x128 double)

Anyone have any thoughts? Happy to clarify further or provide additional workspace variables if needed. Thank you!

```
yname='yname';
xname='xname';
indexname='raw_index';
[NN.yname,NN.xname]=find(ATV_ng_g_raw);
NN.(indexname)=[NN.(xname),NN.(yname)];
nnidxname='HEME_raw_idx';
nndistname='HEME_raw_dist';

[NN.(nnidxname),NN.(nndistname)]=knnsearch(NN.HEME_indices,NN.(indexname)); %knnsearch provides counts vs actual values in the ATV_ng_g_raw array

figure,histogram(NN.(nndistname),'BinMethod','integers');
ylabel('Counts of HEME+ voxels'); 
xlabel('Distance to ARVs (voxels)');
```

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Is it iterating over the window for each pixel, or accumulating the results into a histogram? What distance metric are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm been able to get the counts of non-zero values at the distances but not the actual values in the array. I'm currently using the default 1 as the number of nearest neighbors to find. I'll edit my question to incorporate code that I'm running.